# Setting dynamic content as Pipeline Parameter's default value?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[image: Description]

I have a scenario as I naively describe using the image above. All the components are in Azure Data factory.

Pipeline 1 has few activities and each of them call pipeline 2 for logging some information (as depicted by the gray boxes).
I have defined a list of common logging parameters as `parameters in Pipeline 2`. Some of them are as basic as the `caller pipeline's name or start time.`

I am wondering if there is a way to default these to the caller pipeline's name / start time `rather than` setting them each time in Pipeline 1?

Any other suggestions around the implementation are also highly welcome as I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Hi @Jim, We can also remove the step of defining variables in pipeline 1, and assign dynamic content directly to the parameters in pipeline 2.
[image]

---

Hi @Jim I think we need to use some vairables in pipeline1, then assign dynamic content to these variables, then pass the values to pipeline2 paramters via "Excute Pipeline" activity.

1. Declare two variables `PipelineName` and `StartTime`.
   [image]
2. Assign dynamic content to these variables.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Pass the values to pipeline2 paramters via "Excute Pipeline" activity.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer @Joseph. It needs me to keep the input params as variables in pipeline 1 as well. And eventually I'll end up having multiple sets for each pipeline (if I create other pipelines that need logging). Is this advisable?

Comment: Hi @Jim, We can also omit the first and second steps, please review my updated part.